# Emacs error "Failed to initialize color list unarchiver" when I call it in the terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, emacs, macos-mojave

I've just installed emacs on my MacBook Pro, but when I type "emacs" in my terminal I get this error :

> Emacs-x86_64-10_10[5647:247335] Failed to initialize color list unarchiver: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4864 "*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _initForReadingFromData:error:throwLegacyExceptions:]: non-keyed archive cannot be decoded by NSKeyedUnarchiver" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _initForReadingFromData:error:throwLegacyExceptions:]: non-keyed archive cannot be decoded by NSKeyedUnarchiver}

Then emacs opens correctly, but I can't compile files because of this error.

Comment: How did you install it?  Are you running the one you installed?  (OSX includes Emacs 22.1 as well -- although it does seem rather unlikely that the system-provided executable would be throwing errors like that.)

Comment: You can install it via [homebrew](https://brew.sh/): `brew install --with-cocoa emacs` more info: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsForMacOS#toc14

Comment: installing version 26.1-2 from https://emacsformacosx.com fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I downloaded the latest from https://emacsformacosx.com/ but I still have this error.

Comment: `Error: invalid option: --with-cocoa` @Piotrek

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71878108/m1-mac-errpr-emacs-error-failed-to-initialize-color-list-unarchiver-when-i-ca

Answer (score 36):

This is a known error for Emacs on macOS Mojave. Apparently Emacs has been using a deprecated, and now removed, API. You can follow the thread on [the "emacs-devel" mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2018-09/msg00900.html).

Edit 25 JUL 2019:

Since people still seem to be getting to this question, patches for this issue were pushed the emacs-26 branch [as of Fri, 28 Sep 2018](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2018-09/msg00962.html). The latest version of Emacs 26 (or greater) from source or https://emacsformacosx.com/ will work. If you're just now upgrading and you still get the error/crash with the latest Emacs, delete `~/Library/Colors/Emacs.clr` and restart your new Emacs. Emacs will recreate a non-corrupted version of that file [as documented here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2018-09/msg00993.html).

Comment: Did you try the patch (from 26/9-18)?

Comment: I haven't tried any patches. I'm not in a situation to upgrade right now anyway.

Answer (score 27):

Apparently the issue, mentioned [here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2018-09/msg00900.html), can be fixed just by removing

```
~/Library/Colors/Emacs.clr
```

This file will be recreated the next time Emacs is run

EDIT: when you reboot though, it shows up again

Comment: Thank you @Fabrizio-Miano, getting the latest Emacs version **and** removing this file did the trick for me.

Comment: If one sees this error even after deleting the file, you need to restart emacs twice in succession. So delete the file as above, restart emacs (you will see the error message again), don't delete the file again instead shutdown and restart emacs again. Voila the error's gone!!!

Comment: running emacs 28.2 this solution no longer works. not even with the double-restart

Answer (score 15):

Thank you, @Fabrizio-Miano. I lack the reputation to comment on your answer, but it guided me in the right direction. I was able to suppress this error with a simple one-liner added to the end of my init.el. For others who are interested, I just added:

```
(delete-file "~/Library/Colors/Emacs.clr")
```

For what it's worth, I placed this in a `progn` statement so that it occurs after my theme gets loaded. I'm not sure that it makes a difference, but it seemed like a logical thing to do. Perhaps not an ideal solution, but better than waiting for things to get sorted out in the emacs-26 branch.

Comment: Note: emacs-27 had been causing this issue for me as of 12-26-2020.

Adding this line to the bottom of my .emacs file fixed it!

Comment: I did this, the error still appears